# Zend Framework 2 Library Paths

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Trying to get my feet wet on ZF2 and I've stumbled on my first problem. Say on a module I want to use Shanty_Mongo (an external library to connect to MongoDb)

So I've copied the entire Shanty directory on the library and created a new Model class:

```
namespace Dummy\Model;

use Shanty\Mongo\Document;

class Dummy extends Shanty_Mongo_Document {
  public function setConnections( $connections ) {
    Shanty_Mongo::addConnections($connections);
  }
}
```

(The setConnections() is to be used by DI, if I've understood it well)

This seems to fail to find Shanty_Mongo_Document. Should I add something to the application.config.php to point to the extra library?

Comment: Try `use Shanty\Mongo\Document as Document` and then `class Dummy extends Document`. I'm not too firm with those namespaces but if i understand it correctly it should work out like that

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Actually the Shanty_Mongo follows the directory naming conversion that Zend enforces for it's libraries but I guess it does not work because it doesn't support namespaces. I am trying to figure out exactly how to make it work (http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.loader.html#zend.loader.load)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library `Shanty_Mongo` is an "old" underscore separated library without using namespaces. In ZF2, the style is the same PSR-0 standard but with namespaces (so `Shanty_Mongo` will be `Shanty\Mongo`). However, you are able to load these old style fine with a classmap for example. Then you can use underscore separated classes inside your ZF2 project.

I'd suggest you create a module for this library and put that module under `./vendor` (for "modules providing 3rd party features"). In this module, you can create the following directory structure (I assume the name of the module is ShantyMongo):

```
./vendor/ShantyMongo/
    library/
    Module.php
    autoload_classmap.php
    autoload_function.php
    autoload_register.php
```

The library is a submodule to the Shanty-Mongo git repository. The file `autoload_classmap.php` is a classmap created by the php script `classmap_generator.php` inside the `bin` directory of the ZF2 repository. Then the autoload_function.php can be something simple as this:

```
<?php
return function ($class) {
    static $map;
    if (!$map) {
        $map = include __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
    }

    if (!isset($map[$class])) {
        return false;
    }
    return include $map[$class];
};
```

And autoload_register.php something like this:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(include __DIR__ . '/autoload_function.php');
```

To let the ZF2 application know you have this module, you need to fill the module.php with a `ShantyMongo\Module` class. Something like this should be sufficient:

```
<?php

namespace ShantyMongo;

use Zend\Module\Consumer\AutoloaderProvider;

class Module implements AutoloaderProvider
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

If you add "ShantyMongo" to your modules array in `application.config.php` you now have set up the autoloader for this 3rd party library inside ZF2. You can then use your model as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Dummy\Model;

class Dummy extends Shanty_Mongo_Document {
  public function setConnections ($connections) {
    Shanty_Mongo::addConnections($connections);
  }
}
```

Because ShantyMongo doesn't use namespaces, you don't have that use statement anymore.